# Need to understand few things about class

Tags: perl

Suppose i am having class

```
package Person;
# Class for storing data about a person
#person7.pm
use warnings;
use strict;
use Carp;
my @Everyone;
sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   my $self = {@_};
   bless($self, $class);
   push @Everyone, $self;
   return $self;
}
# Object accessor methods
sub address { $_[0]->{address }=$_[1] if defined $_[1]; $_[0]->{address } }
sub surname { $_[0]->{surname }=$_[1] if defined $_[1]; $_[0]->{surname } }
sub forename { $_[0]->{forename}=$_[1] if defined $_[1]; $_[0]->{forename} }
sub phone_no { $_[0]->{phone_no}=$_[1] if defined $_[1]; $_[0]->{phone_no} }
sub occupation {
   $_[0]->{occupation}=$_[1] if defined $_[1]; $_[0]->{occupation}
}
# Class accessor methods
sub headcount { scalar @Everyone }
sub everyone { @Everyone}
1;
```

And i am calling like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# classatr2.plx
use warnings;
use strict;
use Person;
print "In the beginning: ", Person->headcount, "\n";
my $object = Person->new (
   surname=> "Galilei",
   forename=> "Galileo",
   address=> "9.81 Pisa Apts.",
   occupation => "Philosopher"
);
print "Population now: ", Person->headcount, "\n";
my $object2 = Person->new (
   surname=> "Einstein",
   forename=> "Albert",
address=> "9E16, Relativity Drive",
occupation => "Theoretical Physicist"
);
print "Population now: ", Person->headcount, "\n";
print "\nPeople we know:\n";
for my $person(Person->everyone) {
   print $person->forename, " ", $person->surname, "\n";
}
```

Ouput

```
>perl classatr2.plx
In the beginning: 0
Population now: 1
Population now: 2
People we know:
Galileo Galilei
Albert Einstein
>
```

Doubt -> I am having doubt in this part of code

```
for my $person(Person->everyone) {
   print $person->forename, " ", $person->surname, "\n";
}
```

Query -> here $person is a hash reference. Why we are calling like `$person->forename` . Whereas hash ref should be called as `$person->{$forename}`

Comment: Where is @TLP and mpapec

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$person` is NOT JUST a hash reference; you had this line `bless($self, $class);` earlier. Per the [bless](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html) perldoc;

```
bless REF,CLASSNAME
This function tells the thingy referenced by REF that it is now an object 
in the CLASSNAME package.
```

Comment: I want to +1 this, but I feel like an blessed hashref is still a hashref. I mean, for example, `bless({foo=>'bar'})->{'foo'}` is still `bar`. If you changed "NOT a hash reference" to "not JUST a hash reference", I would definitely upvote.

Comment: U are right. It created one another doubt. Suppose we are having one constructor (new) like the same as declared above. We are having a method say `getSurname`. In that we are doing like `$self->{surname}`. Then how it is working

Comment: Because `$self` is the local name of the same `bless`(ed) hash reference.

Comment: @nuakh Freudian fingers.

Comment: I like how the function is called bless, I seriously don't know if I should hate and fear perl or dive in and love it!

Comment: @Elliott -> How we are able to retrieve using `$person->surname`. I feel it should be `$person->{surname}`.

Comment: @Nitesh it's the Perl Object Oriented syntax, as provided by using `bless`.

Comment: @Elliott -> I tried and found that we can use both ways either `$person->surname` and `$person->{surname}`. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Nitesh, re *"How we are able to retrieve using `$person->surname`"*... `$person->surname` is calling that object accessor (`sub forename`) in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the OP's doubts expressed in comments to Elliott Frisch's answer, the difference between `$person->{surname}` and `$person->surname` is:

`$person->{surname}` directly accesses the object's internal data.  This violates encapsulation and many people consider it a poor practice as a result.

`$person->surname` runs `sub surname` on the `$person` object and returns the result.  In this particular case, the only thing that `sub` does is return the value of `$person->{surname}`, but it could do other things.  For instance, if your `Person` class included the Person's parents, then `$person->surname` would be able to first check whether the Person had a surname defined and, if not, return `$person->father->surname` (or, in some societies, `$person->father->forename . 'sson'`) instead of `undef`.